# jQuery append is not rendering html - it is displaying as text

Tags: html, jquery, css

I am using jQuery to move spans that are under the product-price and product-color classes and appending to the product-title class contents (in parentheses and comma separated with another span), however it is displaying as text instead of html. Can someone tell me how to avoid this and maybe if I am doing this the wrong way? Thanks!

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Playground</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="catalog-courses" class="course-listing">
    <a href="#" title="Title1" class="container">
      <div class="imgwrap">
        <div class="ribbon">
          <span class="ribbon-text">Sold Out</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="product-image">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" alt="Product 1" />
      </div>
      <div class="product-title">Product 1</div>
      <div class="product-description">This is all about product 1</div>
      <div class="product-price">
        <span></span>
      </div>
      <div class="product-color product-callout">
        <span>Blue</span>
      </div>
      <div class="product-tags">
        <span class="product-tag" >
          <span>Tag 1</span>
        </span> 
        <span class="product-tag" >
          <span>Tag 2</span>
        </span> 
        <span class="product-tag" >
          <span>Tag 3</span>
        </span> 
      </div>
      <br/><br/><br/>
    </a> 
    <a href="#" title="Title2" class="container">
      <div class="imgwrap">
        <div class="ribbon">
          <span class="ribbon-text">Available</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="product-image">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" alt="Product 2" />
      </div>
      <div class="product-title">Product 2</div>
      <div class="product-description">This is all about product 2</div>
      <div class="product-price">
        <span>$10</span>
      </div>
      <div class="product-color product-callout">
        <span>Orange</span>
      </div>
      <div class="product-tags">
        <span class="product-tag" >
          <span>Tag 1</span>
        </span> 
        <span class="product-tag" >
          <span>Tag 2</span>
        </span> 
        <span class="product-tag" >
          <span>Tag 5</span>
        </span> 
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <br/><br/><br/>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {

      var i = 0;

      while( i < $('.product-title').length)
      {

        var value1 = $(".product-price span")[0];
        var value2 = $(".product-color span")[0];

        if (value1.innerHTML !='' && value2.innerHTML !='')
        {
          $(this).find('.product-title')[i].append(' \(', '<span class=\"test\">', value1, '\,', value2, '</span>', '\)');
        }
        else if (value1.innerHTML !='') 
        {
          $(this).find('.product-title')[i].append(' \(', value1,value2,'\)');
        }  
        else if (value2.innerHTML !='')
        {
          $(this).find('.product-title')[i].append(' \(', value2,value1,'\)');
        }  
        i++;

      }   
    });
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are expected results? Running the snippet here in the page doesn't show any extra quotes

Comment: I clarified the problem and updated the code. A new span that I am trying to append is being appended with quotes around it. You can see it in the 2nd product. I am new to jQuery and am not sure if I am doing it correctly.  I want the span to be html and not displayed as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your while loop, iterate using .eq jQuery method, like this:

```
if (value1.innerHTML != '' && value2.innerHTML != '') {
  $('.product-title').eq(i).append('<span class=\"test\">', value1, value2, '</span>');
}
else if (value1.innerHTML != '') {
  $('.product-title').eq(i).append(' \(', value1, value2, '\)');
}
else if (value2.innerHTML != '') {
  $('.product-title').eq(i).append(' \(', value2, value1, '\)');
}
```

Sorry for messing up with the white spaces. Please give me a +rep if it helps ;)

Comment: THANK YOU. I modified it a bit. I need to read up on what .eq() does. Is there a better way for me to do this function? Thanks again!